# XPath with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What XPath can I use to select any category with a name attribute specified and any child node author with the value specified.

I've tried different variations of the path below with no success:

```
//quotes/category[@name='Sport' and author="James Small"]
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<quotes>
  <category name="Sport">
   <author>James Small<quote date="09/02/1985">Quote One</quote><quote             date="11/02/1925">Quote nine</quote></author>
  </category>
   <category name="Music">
   <author>Stephen Swann
 <quote date="04/08/1972">Quote eleven</quote></author>
  </category>
  </quotes>
```

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Try:
`//category[@name='Sport' and ./author/text()='James Small']`

Comment: For followers, the error message "Expected ], but found: &&" meant "use the and keyword instead of &&" (as this answer specifies)

Answer (score 45):

**Use**:

```
/category[@name='Sport' and author/text()[1]='James Small']
```

or use:

```
/category[@name='Sport' and author[starts-with(.,'James Small')]]
```

It is a good rule to try to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator whenever possible, because its evaluation can typically be very slow.

Also:

```
./somename
```

is equivalent to:

```
somename
```

so it is recommended to use the latter.

Answer (score 21):

The question is not clear, but what I understand you need to select a category that has name attribute and should have child author with value specified , correct me if I am wrong.

Here is xpath:

```
//category[@name='Required value'][./author[contains(.,'Required value')]]
e.g
//category[@name='Sport'][./author[contains(.,'James Small')]]
```

Comment: So concatenation of condition terms is a logical "and" ?

Answer (score 6):

You can apply multiple conditions in xpath using and, or

```
//input[@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ' and @type='text']

//input[@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ' or @type='text']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, we can do this way as well:

`//category [@name='category name']/author[contains(text(),'authorname')]`

OR

```
//category [@name='category name']//author[contains(text(),'authorname')]
```

To Learn XPATH in detail please visit- [selenium xpath in detail](https://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.com/2019/11/selenium-xpath-in-detail.html)