# XPath expression with conditions on separate parent element child elements

Tags: xml, xpath

Given an XML document like:

```
<SESSION NAME ="TEST" REUSABLE ="NO" SORTORDER ="Binary" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
    <SESSIONEXTENSION DSQINSTNAME ="TEST_SQ" DSQINSTTYPE ="Source Qualifier" NAME ="Relational Reader" SINSTANCENAME ="TEST_SQ" SUBTYPE ="Relational Reader" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Definition" TYPE ="READER"/>
    <SESSIONEXTENSION DSQINSTNAME ="TEST_TG" DSQINSTTYPE ="Source Qualifier" NAME ="Relational Reader" SINSTANCENAME ="TEST_TG" SUBTYPE ="Relational Reader" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Definition" TYPE ="WRITER"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="General Options" VALUE =""/>
</SESSION>
```

I wish to extract the `NAME` attribute of the `SESSION` element for `SESSION` elements for which all of the following are true:

- the child `SESSIONEXTENSION` element's `TYPE` attribute value equals `"READER"`,
- the child `ATTRIBUTE` element's `NAME` attribute value equals `"General Options"` and
- the child `ATTRIBUTE` element's `VALUE` attribute value equals `""`.

The XPath expression

```
/SESSION/SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER']
```

returns a `SESSION` element containing the sought `NAME` attribute value.

However my attempt at an XPath expression specifying all three of the above list of `SESSION` element requirements

```
 /SESSION/SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER']/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME="General Options" and VALUE =""]
```

is not working as expected.

How can I state multiple conditions in an XPath expression where the conditions are for separate children (`SESSIONEXTENSION`, `ATTRIBUTE`) of a parent element (`SESSION`)?

Comment: Try using `@VALUE=...` instead of `VALUE=...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: `/SESSION[SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER'] and ATTRIBUTE[@NAME="General Options" and @VALUE =""]]`

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath returns the `NAME` of `SESSION` elements for which the `ATTRIBUTE` `NAME` is `"General Options"`, the `ATTRIBUTE` `VALUE`is `""` and the `SESSIONEXTENSION` `TYPE`is `"READER"`:

```
//SESSION[ATTRIBUTE[@NAME='General Options'][@VALUE='']][SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER']]/@NAME
```

basically structure of this path is the following:

```
// tag[child1[condition1][condition2]][child[condition3]]/@attr
```

or you can update it to this:

```
// tag[child1[condition1 and condition2] and child[condition3]]/@attr
```

To exclude items by a condition use pattern: `[not(condition)]`

so not to include WRITER, use this:

```
//SESSION[ATTRIBUTE[@NAME='General Options'][@VALUE='']][SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER']][not(SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='WRITER'])]/@NAME
```

Comment: Hi Vitaly, Thank for your answer. If there are two childs with name SESSIONEXTENSION one with TYPE="WRITER" and I want the get the session name only if none of my sessionextension has a type="WRITER". In this case, I should not receive any result. How should I modify my xpath expression?

Comment: you should add another parameter to session, to exclude elements by condition, i'll update answer in a min

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @splash58's comment, I believe that the following XPath returns the desired value ("the `name` of the `session` when `Attribute name` is `General Options` and `values =""` and `sessionextension type="READER"`"):

```
string(/SESSION[SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER'] and ATTRIBUTE[@NAME="General Options" and @VALUE =""]]/@NAME)
```

That XPath evaluated against the XML in the question results in:

```
TEST
```

Remove the `string()` wrap around the XPath to get the attribute name and value - i.e.:

```
/SESSION[SESSIONEXTENSION[@TYPE='READER'] and ATTRIBUTE[@NAME="General Options" and @VALUE =""]]/@NAME
```

which evaluates to

```
NAME=TEST
```

against the above XML.

Above XPaths tested using https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.