# Finding value by class/paragraph values

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the value thats inside the 2nd paragraph text value

```
var id3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-2 item-data-block')]/p[text()='Id. 3']")).Text;
Console.WriteLine(id3);
```

```
<div class="col-xs-2 item-data-block">
<p class="tab">Id. 3</p>
<p>A09999999</p>
</div>
```

Because my webpage have +12 classes with the same name, I also need to use the paragraph text value as an searching attribute. But I dont know how to get the 2nd paragraph value. Ive provided what Ive done... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET WebDriver class has a `FindElements` method that returns a read only collection of `IWebElement` objects. You can build a two step search with this method.

Another solution is described in [XPath with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions)

In your case it should be

```
"//div[@class='col-xs-2 item-data-block' and ./p/text()='Id. 3']"
```

Comment: Doesn't it should be .//p rather ./p , if I am correct , it is a relative path