# Selenium: How to use different locators for an element using POM/PageFactory

Tags: selenium, page-factory

Consider the locator for an Element changes for different versions of the product. And we need to test both the versions of the product.

In this case I would like to use -

1. Multiple locators to locate this single element. (like two different xpaths OR one xpath & one id)
2. Use locator1 for version 1 and locator2 for version 2.

Can you suggest what would be good design to implement this? Is this possible to implement along with `PageFactory`?

I am looking for where I can provide two different types of locators. e.g. xpath and  id. Also should I think of using object repository along with POM to run the test with two different product versions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to implement PageFactory for different versions.

We usually have a build tag in the class  like build_tag = "ver1" or "ver2", you can put your different locators under different UI Map and call according to the version tag.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide or point out to some examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to add multiple conditions on the same locator using OR AND conditions in XPATH.

More detailed at [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions)