# How do I select only visible elements using selectors

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

Hi guys I have the issue as a question that was answered called:
How do I select only visible elements using XPath?

The response was: `//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]//button[.='OK']`.

My question is how do I adapt the above for `aria-hidden='true'`, I'm trying to find elements that are only `aria-hidden='false'`?

I do apologize if my approach is messy, I'm kinda new to asking questions on here

Thanks

Comment: There is no silver bullet to do that because element may be not visible due to lot's of reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding another search criteria, depending on if the `aria-hidden='false'` applies to the `div`

```
//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none')) and @aria-hidden='true')]//button[.='OK']
```

or the `button`

```
//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]//button[.='OK' and @aria-hidden='true']
```

There are some more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you could adapt with your example this way:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-hidden='false']//button[.="OK"]")
```

Don't hesitate to share an URL or HTML code if my answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with more than an hour of searching, trial and error, I found what I was looking for ^-^.. the pain

```
//a[contains(@aria-hidden, 'false') and contains(.,'text')]
```