# What is the XPath to an attribute of an svg Element?

Tags: svg, xpath

Lets say my website contains multiple svg elements and I want to find the following:

```
<svg id="some-svg-id" />
```

How can I find this svg via its id?

I aware that //*[local-name()='svg'] finds all svg elements but how can I narrow it further down to one specific via its id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//svg[@id='some-svg-id']
```

or, since `id` should be unique, this one:

```
//*[@id='some-svg-id']
```

Comment: Thanks but that only displays the symbol in the list of the svg imports on the html and not the physical location of my specifc svg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What does it mean you need the 'physical location' of the svg?

Comment: I want to locate the exact place of one specific svg on the html as an Element and not its "import statement"

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below solution to fix your problem:

//*[name()='svg']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='your-class-name']

or

//*[name()='svg']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='your-class-name']//*[text='rect']

Use * after // something like : //*