# How can we use two different XPaths with AND?

Tags: selenium, xpath

[enter image description here][1]

```
 xpath1=  //*[contains(text(),'Jesaji LOC')] 
 xpath2=  //*[contains(text(),'AutoItem1')]/parent::div/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]/input
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: i tried with AND Operator but its not working,although if i use OR operator then its matching one xpath but i require to match both xpath

Comment: Share HTML in text format.

Comment: Add html code of the page you test and add the elements which locators you are looking for.

Comment: Your question will have chances to be answered if you share the data mentioned in comments.

Comment: hi thank you for helping me as you mention i have updated html code and also added image,i wanted to find xpath of Rate by filtering out Vendor name and Item name

Comment: "//[ etc" wil never select anything because the predicate misses a node. Probably you want this "//*[ etc"

Comment: What are the 2 xpath expressions you wish to combine with the And?

Comment: i wanted to combine xpath1= //[contains(text(),'Jesaji LOC')] xpath2= //[contains(text(),'AutoItem1')]/parent::div/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
//tr/td[div[label='Jesaji LOC']]/table/tbody/tr/td[div[label='AutoItem1']]/following-sibling::td[1]/input
```

Comment: hii siebe can you help me with this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807275/what-is-xpath-for-itemcode-j-air-filled-cylinders-dddfdf/67807631#67807631

Comment: I will give it a try