# what is xpath for ItemCode="J" AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ''@#

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="'J' AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ''@#" aria-describedby="item_grid_ItemCode" class="edit-cell ui-state-highlight">"J" AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ''@#</td>
```

**ItemCode="J" AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ''@#**

tried below xpath which didn't worked

```
1. //td[text()=\""+ItemCode+"\"]
2. //td[text()=\'"+ItemCode+"\']
```

Comment: you are trying to get the text of td tag?

Comment: yes and that text changes everytime with different itemcode,item code have special characters like '," etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usecase is quite tricky.

Depending on which scraping language you use, maybe(I'm not able to test in the moment) use something like this (example JavaScript):

```
let xpath = '//td[text()=concat(\'"J" AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF \',"\'\'\'\'@#") ]';
```

This wil construct this XPath:

```
//td[text()=concat('"J" AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ',"''''@#") ]
```

Meaning: in the case that there is a combi of single or double quotes in your ItemCode you have to build a XPath using the XPath-concat() function.

See these answers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822893/3710053) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542997/3710053) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642125/encoding-xpath-expressions-with-both-single-and-double-quotes).

Comment: thank you Siebe its working  but doesn't solved whole problem as my string will be dynamic and string came from Excel sheet ,there are lots off itemcode string available in excel

Comment: So you have to come up with code that in case you have both: single and double quote, that will build that concat string. Should be doable. Succes

Comment: i created function to generate String like you have mentioned and if i use that generated string in concat it's wokring but if i store in one variable and use that variable inside concat its not working , i use this way => //td[text()=concat(\'"+Itemcode+"\')

Comment: I suggest you just ask a new question with the relevant info, like the content of Itemcode, the name of your scripting-language and the code that you use to build the string.

Comment: thank you i have done that-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903886/how-to-write-xpath-with-concat-function-for-variable

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@class='edit-cell ui-state-highlight']").text
```

Comment: i want to find by text something like //td[text()=\""+ItemCode+"\"], i have multiple itemcode and itemcode contains singel quote or double quotes in it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, is to locate element according to it's text.
If so, please try this:

```
String locator = "//td[contains(text(),'%s')]";
locator = String.format(locator,"'J' AIR FILLED CYLINDERS DDDFDF ''@#");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
```

here you can pass any relevant value inside the `format()` to format a specific XPath locator

Comment: is this applicable for selenium with java ?

Comment: You did not mention what language are you using. Now it is in Java syntax

Comment: apologies for missing ,i am Using Selenium with Java

Comment: No problems, my answer is already updated

Comment: its Not working when your string have both single quote and double quote.