# Dynamic Web Elements Help - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need help locating a dynamic element on a web page.

Even though the id changes each time, it always starts with "ember10", and has the word "btn-primary" in the class, and no other element has both of those characteristics.

I tried using,

```
driver.findElements(By.XPATH,(//*[contains(@id, ‘ember10’)and contains(@class,'btn-primary')
```

But I keep getting Invalid Snytax errors when I run. Anyone know how I would go about locating this dynamic element?

Comment: At minimum you are missing beginning/end double quotes and a right bracket

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

xpath is a string. Wrap all of that up in quotes.

edit: based on @JD2775's comment, I've removed the remainder of this answer.

Comment: Agreed on the first part, definitely NOT on the 2nd part.  `And` conditions exist in Xpath and should be used for this purpose  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247978/xpath-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: Trusting @JD2775 here, since I never use conditionals in xpaths. I'll edit.

Comment: Ok I used the code below and got no errors, it's a mixture of what you both wrote. Is there a way to test if it was correctly located?  I don't want to add  .click() since that will place an order. I've just been coding for 3 days, still have a lot to learn.                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                             POButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@id, 'ember10')] and contains(@class, 'btn-primary')]")

Comment: test your xpath in chrome browser developer console. $x("your xpath") should find your webelement

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath. You are missing double quotes and paranthesis in your xpath. Also if you are trying to find one element, it should be
driver.findElement and not findElements

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//*[contains(@id, ‘ember10’) and contains(@class,'btn-primary')]")
```